# Why Pipeline grouping using Java's stream API collectors taking more time?

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream

I'm creating a Map of Map from a list using Stream API. List contains 10 million records. I have done this with single statement using two 'groupingBy' operations as below. The problem is that this one line statement is taking almost 1.5 minute to execute which became a bottleneck in execution in my performance critical application.

I have given the code I tried below using parallel stream API

```
Map<MyKey, Map<String, List<Person>>> personMap = personList.parallelStream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        person -> new MyKey(person.Id(), person.getPricePointId()),
        Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getWorkType)));
```

It is taking more than 1.5 minute to execute the above code which almost 75 % of my overall execution time. I do not find any other solution faster than this. So my question here is, Is this maximum possible throughput for this much volume of data ? or using downstream(multiple groupingBy) is not right option here ?, If not what should be the right way to reduce the execution time?

Comment: Isn't processing 10 million records in memory an overkill there?

Comment: that 1.5 minutes is from GC activity almost for sure

Comment: @Naman Taking around 3GB to 4GB, but its acceptable and agreed

Comment: how do you even know it's 4GB?

Comment: @Eugene Its is an approximate value. I was monitoring heap size

Comment: Result Map structure is not showing correctly in my code block. I don't know why  !! It is Map<MyKey, Map<String, List<Person>>> personMap

Comment: How much time does it take when using `stream()` instead of `parallelStream()`? How many groups do you have in the outer and inner maps (max, average, etc)? What does a profiling tool say about the hot spots?

Comment: @Holger I have not tried with normal stream. My outer map contains 25K entries and inner map having 5 entries and value (list) contains 700 items. One interesting thing happened now is that it is now taking less than a minute (30-40 seconds) after I restarted my machine. :)

Comment: Are these numbers for the inner maps and lists really average numbers? That would imply that you have >80 million records, not 10 mio. Besides that, you should really try a sequential execution before proceeding.

Comment: @Holder each inner map entry will have 100 items, not 700. sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0):

what youre are doing is a bad idea querying a 10 million records takes a lot of memory
so, group your query into limit and start point and divide  queries according to limit and start point and run every query in separate thread at last join the thread. it will be much more faster as well efficient for your use case

Comment: this is comment, not an answer

Comment: I'm already making use of multithreading using parallel stream. So I believe stream API would do best out of possible